# Windows Store-app with login-screen

Tags: xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I need my program to start up with an login-screen, but I can not figure out how to make it look pretty. 
I tried with a code, that looks like the following, but I do not think it is the "true way" to do it

```
<Page.Resources>
   <Grid Style="{StaticResource LayoutRootStyle}">
      <TextBlock x:Name="pageTitle" Grid.Column="1" Text="{StaticResource AppName}" Style="{StaticResource PageHeaderTextStyle}"/>
   </Grid>
   <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="647,31,0,0" Grid.Row="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBlock" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
   <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="634,62,0,0" Grid.Row="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
   <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="647,128,0,0" Grid.Row="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBlock" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
   <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="634,167,0,0" Grid.Row="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
   <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="632,243,0,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
```

Can anybody tell me how to create a pretty login-screen as start-screen 
I have though of a dialog, as it should not be possible to go back to it, but how can I create it with an empty background?

**UPDATE**

Thanks to DanielRozo in his answer below, my code now looks like this

```
<Popup IsOpen="True" Margin="200" Height="260" Width="900">
   <Grid Height="250">
      <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource HeaderTextStyle}" Text="Login" Margin="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="50" />
      <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=SubheaderTextStyle}" Text="" Margin="0,63,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
      <TextBox Name="InputUsername" Margin="0,63,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="40" Width="650"/>
      <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=SubheaderTextStyle}" Text="" Margin="0,138,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
      <PasswordBox Name="InputPassword" Margin="0,0,138,0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="40" Width="650"  />
      <Button Name="Login" Content="" Margin="200,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"  />
      <Button Name="Cancel" x:Uid="LoginPopupCancel" Content="" Margin="300,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
   </Grid>
</Popup>
```

But it does not work, when I rotate the screen, so I created [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13904944/login-popup-not-working-when-rotating) 
I also needs help to figure out how to set the page to a login-page

Comment: What about the appearance of the above code do you not like?

Comment: I do not think it meets the guidelines

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/hh465424

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using the Popup class? I think it's a better approach of what you want. Something like:

```
 <Popup Margin="200" IsOpen="True">
        <Grid Margin="0" Height="322" Width="865">
            <TextBlock Text="App Name Login" Style="{StaticResource HeaderTextStyle}" Margin="252,4,200,266"></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Text="User" Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=SubheaderTextStyle}" Margin="244,63,498,223"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="user" Margin="440,62,180,216"></TextBox>
            <TextBlock Text="Pass" Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=SubheaderTextStyle}" Margin="244,137,498,149"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="pass" Margin="440,138,180,138"></TextBox>
            <Button Name="Login" Content="Login" Margin="613,230,0,54"></Button>
            <Button Name="Cancel" Content="Cancel" Margin="489,230,0,54"></Button>
        </Grid>
    </Popup>
```

Comment: How do I show the Popup as the first thing, when the user starts the app?

Comment: Anyways, I figured it out. The code should just be placed on the MainPage. 
Now I only need to center the Popup

Comment: Yep, just place it in there. I asume you can handle the button Click. Also, it's a good idea to remember the user's credentials and store them in Roaming Settings; if they're present and are valid, don't show the popup

Comment: As it could be a computer, that is just setup to be running, and different users can login to the program using the same Windows-account, I need to ask the user for login when the program starts. The only problem I have is to remove the MainPage from the NavigationService

Comment: There's no need to remove it, just populate it acording to login; but if you want, ask it on a different question and I'll take a look at it.

Comment: What do you mean by "populate it according to login"?

Comment: If login fails, do nothing. Is login is succesful, from code behind:
     popup.IsOpen=false; //you need to put a name to the popup in XAML

And then just fill the data in MainPage

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I'd highly suggest the Web Auth Broker. If the user is auth'd using their LiveID, the WAB will provide you that credential, allowing you to not have to have credential re-entry for connected accounts. :)

Answer (score 0):

I know that you've already marked another question as answer, but if you *need* to log in users into your app I think you should definitely take a look at the SplashScreen API. Overriding the default splashscreen, you'll have the users being always prompted with the username/password fields every time the app starts; moreover, you can never go back to the splashscreen, which is exactly what you say you need.

You should look at this sample: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Splash-screen-sample-89c1dc78 . I also suggest you to download Evernote from the market: trying an app made with the Splashscreen API may give you a better idea of what I'm saying.